# Making a query on my database using user input

Tags: php, database, querying

I am writing some code that will allow the user to enter there location and month of the year and be presented with stars viewable that month from their location. I have my database completed and query working on mySQl but trying to implement it on the web page and have come accross some difficulties, I have two inputs the user can make and the program below that runs the function, If anyone can spot any errors, The function will not output any data when location and month entered but when nothing is entered and submit pressed it outputs events but cannot figure out why.

The search function is below and then the event. php is below that

```
<?php
/**
* Performs a search
*
* This class is used to perform search functions in a MySQL database
*
*
*  
*/
class search {
/**
* MySQLi connection
* @access private
* @var object
*/
private $mysqli;

/**
* Constructor
*
* This sets up the class
*/
public function __construct() {
// Connect to our database and store in $mysqli property
$this->connect();
}
/**
* Database connection
* 
* This connects to our database
*/
private function connect() {
$this->mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'conor', 'trevor29', 'site_db' );
}

/**
* Search routine
* 
* Performs a search
* 
* @param string $search_term The search term
* 
* @return array/boolen $search_results Array of search results or false
*/
public function search($search_term, $search_term1) {
// Sanitize the search term to prevent injection attacks
$sanitized = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($search_term);
$sanitized1 = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($search_term1);


// Run this Query
$query =$this ->mysqli->query("
SELECT event_name FROM event
INNER JOIN event_month
ON event.event_id = event_month.event_id
INNER JOIN month
ON event_month.month_id = month.month_id
INNER JOIN location
ON location.hemisphere = event.hemisphere
WHERE month_name LIKE '%{$sanitized}%'
AND city LIKE '%{$sanitized1}%'
");

// Run the query
//$query = $this->mysqli->query("
//SELECT *
//FROM event inner join location
//ON event.event_id = location.event_id 
//WHERE city LIKE'%{$sanitized}%'
//");

// Check results
if ( ! $query->num_rows ) {
  return false;
}

// Loop and fetch objects
while( $row = $query->fetch_object() ) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}

// Build our return result
$search_results = array(
  'count' => $query->num_rows,
  'results' => $rows,
);

return $search_results;
}
}
```

this code below is the event page that calls the search function above
    ?php

```
//getname
session_start();

//Check if search data was submitted

$search_results="";

if  (isset( $_GET['s'])){

// Include the search class
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/class-search.php' );

// Instantiate a new instance of the search class
$search = new search();

// Store search term into a variable
$search_term =($_GET['s']);
$search_term1 =($_GET['m']);


// Send the search term to our search class and store the result
$search_results = $search->search($search_term, $search_term1);


}
?>
```

This below is where the user inputs their location and month

### Search Events

Search
    ">

```
<form action= "" method = "get">
<div class= "form-field">
<label for="search-field">Search</label>
<input type = "type" name ="m" placeholder = "Enter the month" results="5" value = "<?php $search_term1; ?>">
<input type ="submit" value = "Search">
 </div>
```

If anyone can see any errors or mistakes it would be great help the more I work on it the further away I am getting

Comment: <input type = "type" should be `<input type = "text"` ....also, where is `s`

Comment: there's also no `s` name attribute/input neither nor did you echo `value = "<?php $search_term1; ?>`.  and what is this supposed to do? `results="5"`... Debug your code.

Comment: Also if the search terms are optional the condition should be an `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: `if  (isset( $_GET['s'])){...}` will NEVER happen.

Comment: you have an answer below; ask them now. It's out of my hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the easiest error I can see from a limited snapshot like this is you are passing the month through `$search_term1` HOWEVER you are searching for `city` with `$sanitized1` which leads me to believe you have the month and city reversed in the query.

Comment: Thanks I have been looking at this for so long It would have been awhile before I would have spotted that

Comment: It appears to be showing results now but if the button is submitted with no input it outputs all the events in the data base and not sure why

Comment: Because you are using `like` `like '%%'` is the same as saying `get all`  you might want to make some extra code to deal with an empty field or `if ($field == '') then $field = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';` to prevent that